# Access custom thread methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I have created a custom thread with extra methods. I have created several threads in the loop.

I m interested to know if I can execute the extra method using Thread.getAllStackTraces() as shown below.

```
public class CustomThread extends Thread
{

    int pid;

    CustomThread(int processID)
    {
        this.pid = processID;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println("Thread running");
    }

    public void printDetails()
    {
        System.out.println("PID "+this.pid);
    }
}


public class Main 
{

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
       for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
           CustomThread ct = new CustomThread(1);
           ct.start();
       }
   } 
   System.out.println(Thread.getAllStackTraces().get(0).printDetails); <- Is it possible to access the method like this?

}
```

Comment: `printDetails` method belongs to CustomThread, but `Thread.getAllStackTraces().get(0)` returns `StackTraceElement[]` (an array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While typing this I see that Evgeny has beaten me in typing speed, however I'd like to point out a few things. His method is correct but won't give you any output:

First of here is an elaboration on the method:

```
Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> map = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
Set<Thread> threads = map.keySet();//Get the keys of the map, in this case the key is the thread
for(Thread thread : threads){//iterate over all the threads
    if(thread instanceof CustomThread){//check to see if it is one of our custom threads
        CustomThread custom = (CustomThread)thread;//cast it to a custom thread
        custom.printDetails();//call your method
    }
}
```

And this method won't give you any feedback (yet) because your threads are already dead by the time this runs.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Thread running");
    while(true){}//add this to keep the thread alive
}
```

So to test it you can just add an infinite while loop to the Thread and then the method will work.

Also all of your Threads will have the same PID as instead of using `i` as the PID in your loop you are using `1`. So to give all your custom Thread a different PID you could use:

```
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
  CustomThread ct = new CustomThread(i);
  ct.start();
}
```

I hope this helps :)

P.S. Evgeny was first so credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 3):

> `Thread.getAllStackTraces()` Returns a map of stack traces for all live threads. The map keys are threads and each map value is an array of StackTraceElement that represents the stack dump of the corresponding Thread.

As `Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]>` is returned you can't get element with `get(0)`. You have to provide `Thread` instance as a key but you will get `StackTraceElement[]`.

 In your case you need `Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet().get(0)` to get first thread or you can iterate over the whole map keys

```
for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
   if (t instanceof CustomThread) {
       ((CustomThread)t).printDetails();;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the reply. I used this answer, however, the loop iterates once although there are 5 threads created. If I remove the "instanceof" conditional statement, it iterates all the 5 threads.

Comment: @Vimlan.G Loop iterates once because other threads finish their work before `getAllStackTraces()` is invoked. Roan mentioned it in his answer. You need to add something to `CustomThread` run method to make threads work longer, e.g. `Thread.sleep()` or infinite loop.  If you remove the "instanceof" you may get ClassCastException.